# Syncing MySQL RDS tables to Snowflake

Tags: etl, amazon-rds, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, change-data-capture

I have a MySQL RDS database that holds configuration/dimension tables. I also have transaction data streaming into Snowflake. I want the MySQL tables to be synced in Snowflake so that they are available in Snowflake because I will be writing a compute job that will join the config/dimension tables with the transactional data in Snowflake.
What is the best way to sync the tables from MySQL to Snowflake at a certain frequency?

Comment: please define what 'best way' means from your standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

In order to replicate MySQL tables towards Snowflake, you could use one of the following:

- [Fivetran](https://fivetran.com/) (cloud-native for on-premise and cloud database replication)
- [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) (open-source distributed platform for change data capture)

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm part of the team working on the solution suggested below*

In addition to the solutions that were already mentioned, you can also create a data application using [Turbine](https://docs.meroxa.com/beta-overview/) to sync your tables from MySQL to SnowflakeDB in real-time.

Depending on your current tech stack and the language you feel most comfortable developing in, you can create an application using any of the following libraries:

- Python: [turbine-py](https://github.com/meroxa/turbine-py)
- GoLang: [turbine-go](https://github.com/meroxa/turbine-go)
- JavaScript: [turbine-js](https://github.com/meroxa/turbine-js)